# I want to select in Mat Table with selection Based on dropdown value in angular

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material, material-table

I have created a Table with selection using angular material. Now I want to check some particular rows in onchange method of a dropdown.
I did so far:

1. Created the table
2. Load value in database
3. Created dropdown and onChange method
4. Created a save button that gives me the selected value and my dropdown value.

Now I am unable to check the row for the value based on onChange of the dropdown.
My dataSource:

```
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
  { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' },
  { position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li' },
  { position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be' },
  
];
```

In onChange of my dropdown let say I want to check only this two-row

```
 { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
  { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' },
```

**Noted**:I should be able to check or uncheck after loading value and get a new checked value in my save button
[**Here is my code in stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-psbv9x?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-selection-example.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change your `onSelectRole` like this

```
 onSelectRole(e: any) {
    this.selection.clear();
    if(e==1){
      const CheckThisRow = this.dataSource.data.filter(x=>x.position==1)
      this.selection.select(...CheckThisRow);
    }
    if(e==2){
      const CheckThisRow = this.dataSource.data.filter(x=>x.position==4)
       this.selection.select(...CheckThisRow);
    }
  }
```

NB:pls make changes as you need

Comment: Sir, Your code is working fine. But here you filter with a static value.In my senior Let`s say on dropdown onchange method I got this list (CheckThisRow ) from a database which has 2 array  
CheckThisRow = [
{ position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },

{ position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' },]
now I want to check this two row for a particular role.

Comment: @Rakin pls replace the static values with your conditions...